# Proving the propositional tableau sound and complete

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

There is something fundamental that stops me from understanding the proofs for the propositional tableau.

- (1) soundness proves that all theorems that can be proved are valid
- (2) completeness proves that all the valid statements are theorems.

When proving soundness and completeness of the tableau:

- (3) For soundness: given a fully expanded open branch with root $A$, then there is a $v \vDash A$ [i.e.$A$ is satisfiable -- MA].
- (4) For completeness: given a tableau with a [should be *every* -- PS] branch closed, then $A$ is unsatisfiable.

Now, I understand soundness and completeness on their own, and the practical proofs that we do for (3) and (4). But I can’t understand why we prove exactly those statements and I can’t draw the relation between (1) to (3) and (2) to (4). Why would those make it sound and complete?

Instead of (4) I was expecting the inverse of (3) like:
given a $v \vDash A$, then the tree has an open branch.

Can someone clarify on how we can prove it sound and complete and why this would do it?

Answer (score 2):

It is the other way about: you use (4) to prove (1), and (3) to prove (2)! For remember, a wff $\varphi$ is declared proved by a tableau if the tree stating with the *negation* of $\varphi$ closes.

Thus, for soundness (1): We want to show that if a tableau starting with $\neg\varphi$ closes, so the tableau declares $\varphi$ to be proved, then $\varphi$ really *is* valid.

By the corrected version of (4), if a tree starting $\neg\varphi$ closes, then $\neg\varphi$ is unsatisfiable, so $\varphi$ is always true, i.e. is valid. QED.

For completeness (2): We want to show that if $\varphi$ is valid, a tableau starting $\neg\varphi$ closes. That is to say, contraposing, if some tableau starting $\neg\varphi$ stays open, then $\varphi$ is not valid.

But by (3) if some tableau starting $\neg\varphi$ stays open, i.e. has an open branch, there is a valuation which makes $\neg\varphi$ true, so $\varphi$ is not valid. QED.

Comment: in order to prove soundness and completeness, do I not have to prove them by induction?

Comment: @graphtheory92 - Completeness : NO. Soundmess : YES with *proof systems* based on axioms+rules of inference and the definition of *derivation* as a finite sequnce of formulae obtained starting from axioms by application of inference rules (like *modus ponens*). In this case, you prove soundness by *induction* on the *length* of the derivation.

Comment: "We prove by induction on the number n of expansions on the tableau, that there always is some branch B with v |= B. Base case: if n = 0, no expansions have been applied. There is a single branch containing only A, and we know v |= A. Inductive hypothesis: we assume that n expansions have been applied, and there is a branch B such that v |= B." is what I found on a professor slide :/ How would you prove that then?

Comment: @Peter, I see you state everything in negation. Could I say: tableau of A is open -> A is satisfiable (soundness) and A is satisfiable -> tableau of A is open (completeness) ?

Comment: @graphtheory92 - the argument shows that if a branch is *satisfiable*, then also the "root formula" $A$ is *satisfiable*. With the *Lemma* that every open branch is satisfiable, it give us your (3), i.e. "given a fully expanded open branch with root $A$, then there is a $v$ such that $v \vDash A$.

Comment: that clarifies everything! grazie!

Comment: @graphtheory92 - you are welcome !

Comment: @graphtheory92 - about your question to Peter, if the tableau for $A$ is open, then $A$ is *sat*; but $A$ is *sat* iff $\lnot A$ is **not** *valid*. Thus, contraposing, if $\lnot A$ **is** *valid*, then the tableau for $A$ must close. The closure of the tableau is the equivalent in this system of *provability*. Thus, if $\lnot A$ is *valid* then we may prove it with a closed tableau starting form $A$. Thus, validity implies provability, and this is *completeness* (and **not** soundness).

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear. My statement ` tableau of A is open -> A is satisfiable (soundness)` and `A is satisfiable -> tableau of A is open (completeness)` are then wrong (or vague)?

Comment: To repeat, tableau of A open -> A is satisfiable, if that's your proposition (3) again, is **not** soundness for a tableau system: it's what you need to prove completeness. As explained in my answer. Or check out the detailed proofs in my *Introduction to Formal Logic*.

Comment: Perhaps you are being led astray by terminology: a tableau for A in the sense of a tableau to test whether A is valid is not a tableau for A in the sense of a tableau starting with A. Confusingly(?) A tableau for A in the first sense is a tableau for not-A in the second sense.

Comment: why would the proof differ and how?

Comment: @graphtheory92 - rewrite the condition (3) : "given a fully expanded open branch with root A, then $A$ is satisfiable" as (3') : "if there exists a branch with root $A$ that does **not** close, then $A$ is satisfiable". Now we apply the logical rule of conversion : $(P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow (\lnot Q \rightarrow \lnot P)$, where $P$ is "there exists a branch with root $A$ that does **not** close" and $Q$ is "$A$ is satisfiable". Thus, we infer form (3') the equivalent (3'') : "if $A$ is **not** satisfiable, then does **not** exists a branch with root $A$ that does **not** close". 1/2

Comment: This in turn is : "if $A$ is **not** satisfiable, then **all** branches with root $A$ close". But $A$ is **not** sat iff $\lnot A$ is *valid*; thus we arrive at $(3^3)$ : "if $\lnot A$ is valid, then **all** branches with root $A$ close". Finally, switch $A$ with $\lnot A$ and vice versa to get $(3^4)$ : "if $A$ is valid, then **all** branches with root $\lnot A$ close". This is the statement of *Completenss Theorem* for tableau : "If $X$ is valid, then every completed tableau starting with $\lnot X$ must close".